# How to edit an inner html, save it and display the same in a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

To edit an inner html and save it. that is download it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
            $(document).ready(function () {


             function downloadInnerHtml(filename, elId, mimeType) {
                 var elHtml = document.getElementById(elId).innerHTML;
                 var link = document.createElement('a');
                 mimeType = mimeType || 'text/plain';

                 link.setAttribute('download', filename);
                 link.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + mimeType + ';charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(elHtml));
                 link.click();
             }

             var fileName = 'tags.txt';

            $('.edit').click(function () {
                $(this).hide();
                $('#content').addClass('editable');
                $('p').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
                $('.save').show();
            });

            $('.save').click(function () {
                $(this).hide();
                $('#content').removeClass('editable');
                $('p').removeAttr('contenteditable');
                $('.edit').show();
                downloadInnerHtml(fileName, 'content', 'text/plain');
            });



        });
    </script>
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: It works only in chrome and not in firefox how to make it work even in fire fox

Comment: what happen in firefox? is there an error?

Comment: It won't download

Comment: ok corrected, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have no explanation for this fire reaction but you may try *JQuery* instead of *DOM*

```
  var link  = ($('<a>').insertAfter($('body')))[0]
```

---

> EDIT: Ok found it! you need just to append it to the Body of page.

Inject this:

```
document.body.appendChild(link);
```

Before calling `Click()` method.